# Why not "assented on 1999-06-17"?

Tags: word-usage

I have two issues for the below phrases:

> Extradition Act
>   S.C. 1999, c. 18
>   Assented to 1999-06-17

1. What does *c. 18* means?
2. Can i write *Assented on 1999-06-17*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think c. means "chapter".

No, the act wasn't "assented", it was "assented to", because "assent" is not a transitive verb.

> They assented to the act.

not

> *They assented the act.

If you ask why that is, there is no reason: it's just the way English happens to be. Some verbs have it as an option ("protest" and "appeal" always take "against" in British English, but don't always do so in American English). But "assent", as far as I know, always requires "to".